# Suspending/Resuming an Async Process with std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

Let us assume that a following class exists:

```
class MySession {
 public:
    run(); // can only be invoked once, starts a child _run() process as an async process
    suspend();
    resume();
 private:
    // basic implementation
    run_() {
       while(condition) {
         runMyDefaultOperation();
         // either waits for interval, or if suspended, waits until resume is called 
         waitFor(interval); 
       }
    }
};
```

This works perfectly fine, but it limits in terms of scalability. This implementation restricts me from suspending in "blocks". To get around this I would need to need to check for a `is_suspended` state for arbitrarily smaller blocks of code.

Is this design pattern acceptable, or is there another one that I should be utilizing instead for a task such as this?

Comment: Check `game loop` pattern, it primarily applies to games and other real time applications. The logic is, in order to avoid different experiences on different hardwares, the processing time for previous operation(rendering a frame on games) is calculated and if the computer is too fast this means it will process it very fast thus put that on hold for a while, if hardware projcess just on time that will pass without any waiting so they will be aligned regardless of their hardware power

Comment: Spinning, even with a wait, is often a bad idea.  Not always.  The best patterns for the kinds of such operations you are doing ends up being sensitive to what you are doing -- what you are "spinning on".  You have abstracted out all details about what you are "spinning on".  This makes answering your question an act of mind reading.  Now, people are surprisingly good at mind reading, but it is still a waste of the people answering your question's time.

Comment: What I am doing internally is actually irrelevant in my case.  A function is invoked that is unaffected by any of the data owned by `MySession`. I did leave the intervals, which will be anywhere from 1-10+ minutes.

Comment: Yakk: there was no explicit spinning in the question, condition variable would work, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this design pattern is acceptable, and also scalable: the way to scalability here is to divide Session's job into smaller chunks, so runMyDefaultOperation() would execute a small chunk of code every time.

You can use [command pattern](http://go/wiki/Command_pattern) to some extent to help structuring jobs.

As a side note, a suitable mechanism to implement `suspend`, `resume` and `wait` is [condition variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).